# How do I see see version of tcsh that is running?

Tags: unix, shell, version, tcsh

How do I see the current version of tcsh is running in my unix terminal?

Comment: @Dennis: barely ;-)  zsh forever!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the `version` variable:

```
% echo $version 
tcsh 6.14.00 (Astron) 2005-03-25 (i386-intel-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,sm,rh,color,filec
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried before researching and posting the question. Why doesn't it work? (I would get the same result if I typed this in bash.)
env |  grep -i ver
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=273

Comment: What you're looking for is a shell variable, which you won't find in the environment.  BASH has its own equivalent called BASH_VERSION.  Either can be substituted on the command line or found using the `set` built-in.  TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION is added to the environment by Apple's terminal program and has nothing to do with the shell you're running.

Comment: You can use either `$version` (as shown) or `$tcsh`, which gives you just the version number (such as "6.14.00"). (I once ran into a situation where some system startup script, probably /etc/csh.cshrc or /etc/csh.login, used a `$version` variable internally, which stepped on tcsh's `$version`.)